# How can I make the following regex also match

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)(.+\.)?(.+)(\..*)$/gm
```

The list is:

```
https://localhost
https://www.example.com
https://www.subdomain.example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com
http://example..com
http://....example.com
```

It matches:

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.subdomain.example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com
http://example..com
http://....example.com
```

The problem is that, I want to match `https://localhost`, and I do not want to match:

```
http://example..com
http://....example.com
```

---

Why am I not using just `/^https?:\/\/.+$/gm`? Because I need to capture them in groups. So by that, I mean:

For `https://www.subdomain.example.com`

```
Group 1: https://
Group 2: www.subdomain.
Group 3: example
Group 4: .com
```

And for `https://localhost`, it would be:

```
Group 1: https://
Group 3: localhost
```

For `https://www.example.com`:

```
Group 1: https://
Group 2: www.
Group 3: example
Group 4: .com
```

---

So, in:

```
https://localhost
https://www.example.com
https://www.subdomain.example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com
http://example..com
http://....example.com
```

I only want to match:

```
https://localhost
https://www.example.com
https://www.subdomain.example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com
```

Btw, it should not match invalid urls:

```
http:
https://
```

Only full urls.

#### Btw, any subdomains.

#### Here is a link: https://regex101.com/r/z7V33F/1

How can I achieve this?

Comment: At this point I'd consider writing a function to do this instead. You'd easily be able to do it there, you can check for specific strings that are important in this context, and you can make it readable, understandable and most importantly, maintainable. regexes are unmaintainable enough as they are, this extra non-normal functionality you are piling on top of your existing case will not make it any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
^(https?:\/\/)((?:[^.\/]+\.)*?)([^.\/\n]+)(\.[^.\/]+)?$
^(https?://)((?:[^./]+\.)*?)([^./]+)(\.[^./]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mjoLoY/4). The second pattern variant is for those engines that do not require `/` regex delimiters. *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(https?:\/\/)?` - an optional Group 1: `https://` or `http://`
- `((?:[^.\/]+\.)*?)` - Group 2: zero or more occurrences (but as few as possible) of one or more chars other than `.` and `/` followed with a `.`
- `([^.\/]+)` - Group 3: one or more chars other than `.` and `/`
- `(\.[^.\/]+)?` - an optional Group 4: a `.` char and then one or more chars other than `.` and `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks my master.... I am happy that I am able to meet you again :)

Comment: I cannot accept an answer for 7 mins it says. So, thanks

Comment: I have found a problem. It also matches just `http:`.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Then include this example in the question. What is the requirement then? If the protocol must be present, use `(https?:\/\/)`  instead of `(https?:\/\/)?`.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana See https://regex101.com/r/mjoLoY/2, add the `(?!https?:\/*$)` lookahead after `^`.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Or, consider using `(?!https?:\/*$|[\w-]*$)` lookahead to also fail strings like `aaa-a-a-a-aa` or `dtrfegtre`. See https://regex101.com/r/mjoLoY/3

Comment: Update your question with https://regex101.com/r/mjoLoY/3. That answers it properly

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana I updated. Please look at [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103906/how-can-i-make-the-following-regex-also-match/66104019#comment116871419_66104019), I suggested making `https?://` pattern obligatory. So, is that what you need? To make sure the URL starts with `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: Umm.. yes that is

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(https?://)((?:[\w-]+\.){0,2}?)([^.]+)(\.[^.]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODswIj/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(https?://)`: Match `https://` or `http://` and capture in group #1
- `((?:[\w-]+\.){0,2}?)`: Match first part of domain and capture in *optional* group #2
- `([^.]+)`: Match (last-1)th part of domain name and capture in group #3
- `(\.[^.]+)?`: Match last part of domain and capture in *optional& group #4
- `$`: End

Comment: Now, I am unable to choose from which answer to accept...

Comment: Nice. But little remark. Wouldnt this match `https://` which was supposed to fail (if I read correctly)?

Comment: Hm, you may be right, but I was confused about the multiline modifier thinking this might be a block of URL's together. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/cAp5pg/1) about what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
^(https?:\/\/)(www\.(?:[^.\n]+\.)??)?([^\.\n]+)(\.[^\.\n]+)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yc2Ybo/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(https?:\/\/)` - 1st Capture group holding "http", an optional "s" and the two literal forward slashes.
- `(www\.(?:[^.\n]+\.)??)?` - A 2nd optional capture group holding literally "www" followed by a literal dot and an optional lazy group of 1+ characters that are not a dot and newline character untill a literal dot.
- `([^\.\n]+)` - A 3rd capture group holding 1+ character not being literal dot or newline character.
- `(\.[^\.\n]+)?` - Optional 4th capture group holding a literal dot and 1+ characters not being a dot or newline character.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: The groups are messed up. Look at `https://www.example.com` in your solution.

Comment: Nice. But, I do not know whose answer to accept yet.... I keep changing my mind abt that

Comment: Don't worry. Accept whichever as you did. Upvote those that have been helpfull. I'm personally not bothered. I just like the "puzzle" aspect of these questions =) @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana

Comment: I think yours saves more memory??? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yours only matches the needed. But the others' matches also the other groups....

Comment: I think the other answers are completely fine @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana. I usually look at the amount of steps it takes to process a pattern. There is a slight difference between the answers. That's correct. I'm not so techwise that I would know about internal memory usage. =)

Comment: But, don't the unnecessary groups use more memory??

Comment: And, yours only matches `www`?? forgot to mention in question

Comment: Yes I wrote it as such that it needs to match "www" literally as per your examples @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana.